# NSView Remove after animation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nsview

I do not know why it is proving to be so difficult, but basically I want to animate an NSView across my screen, and once it is done that animation, remove that NSView. It however seems that I can find absolutely no reference on how to do this. Can someone please help?

I am starting my animation like this

```
NSRect frame = blob.frame;
frame.origin.x = animationStopX;
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:timeToDisappear];
[[blob animator] setFrame:frame];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

I have no way of getting a callback from this once it completes or anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right after your `beginGrouping` statement, add this:

```
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setCompletionHandler:^{
        [self.blob removeFromSuperview];
    }];
```

`setCompletionHandler:` is a method in the `NSAnimationContext` class.

Comment: aww man I wish I would have seen this a few days ago. I ended up making a separate run loop that just parsed through and checked some properties. If certain conditions were met, I ended up removing the object.

I will keep it in mind next time I try to do anything like this.

Comment: setCompletionHandler is available for OS X 1.7 and later.

Comment: Bear in mind, 'setCompletionHandler' will be called even if the animation was 'cancelled', i.e. if you have an event firing another call to a method which animations 'blob' and in its 'setCompletionHandler' you [self.view addSubview self.blob], you could effectively end up hanging you app in SpinLock OR you could have undesirable results such as removal of view even though you just added it. That's because the app could pause the mainThread, give priority to another dispatch call and call the two 'cancellation blocks' out of order.

Answer (score 1):

In case 10.6 or below (and thus NSAnimationContext's `completionHandler`) is not an option this approach just uses blocks and will work on 10.6+:

```
   double delayInSeconds = 1.0;
   dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
   dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
      [mySubView removeFromSuperview];
   });
```