# NSView.animator isAnimating raises error

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, nsview

I have some *NSView* subclass that I'm animating (changing frame and alpha value). Sometimes I would need to stop the animation, however I'm keep getting error

Here is a code:

```c
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:1.5f];
[textView.animator setFrame:frame];
[textView.animator setAlphaValue:0.0];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];

if ([textView.animator isAnimating]) { // Here the exception is raised
    NSLog(@"%@ is animating!", textView);
}
```

I am trying to call `[textView.animator isAnimating]` but that just gives me

```
Exception detected while handling key input.
*** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:isAnimating] called!
```

Example project with the code is at https://bitbucket.org/lukaszb/animationartifacts/src/0dc41660f26dd3b629c28bbbda6eb647

I could probably add some `isAnimating` property to my `NSView` subclass and set it at animation start and at the completion handler, however that could also lead to some race condition issue I suppose.

Could anyone help me how to detect if a view is being animated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `NSView` nor its animator have a property `animating`, so you cannot just query that value.

However, as you suggest, you can define your own property for that purpose. The trick is to set it back to `NO` once the animation is done, which you can do using the `completionHandler` property on the current animation context:

```
[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[NSAnimationContext currentContext].completionHandler = ^{ self.animating = NO; };
// ... set up your animation ...
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

Note that the block is called on the main thread (as indicated in the documentation), so it will ensure that the state is consistent as long as you always set the `animating` property on the main thread. Since you are dealing with UI code, that is probably the case.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360150/nsview-remove-after-animation